# Python package that compares an SQLAlchemy ORM to a pre-existing database schema?

Tags: python, database, orm

Is there a Python package that will compare a live database schema to one defined in an SQLAlchemy ORM?

I have a decent size MS SQL Server instance (6 databases, ~200 total tables) that I need to make an SQLAlchemy ORM for.

SQLAlchemy has very handy [reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html) which allows it to read information about a table and essentially generate an SQLAlchemy table object from that information.

What I'd like to do is write tests for my ORM that utilize reflection to verify that the ORM tables as written match those that already exist in the database. Has someone already made a Python package that does this?

I'll be using [`sqlacodegen`](https://github.com/agronholm/sqlacodegen) to initially populate my ORM, but as the live schema changes I need to be able to run a test on my ORM and see where my table objects are no longer up-to-date.